# What is the name of this kind of integral called?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\int_x^{x+n} f(t) dt$$ What is this kind of integral called? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could call this the Average Value of $f(x)$ on the interval $[x, x+n]$, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a moving average.

Answer (score -1):

I've heard it referred to as an integral with respect to a "dummy" variable.

Comment: That describes _all_ integrals.

Comment: @Akiva To reword what I was thinking, the function has to do with changing the limits of integration, rather than changing a parameter of the function under the integral itself. In this case, x does not appear anywhere other than the limits of integration. Or are we not on the same page?